# What would cause MySQL to not respond to connections on 127.0.0.1 but work fine using localhost?

Tags: networking, centos, mysql

having a strange issue on one of my CentOS servers. I've noticed MySQL randomly will not respond if I try to connect via 127.0.0.1 in my PHP script. Basically, 1 out of 20 requests or so will usually fail. Connecting via 'localhost' does not exhibit the same issue, I've tried accessing the same script 1000s of times over a 24 hour period and every request went through.

I realize when using 'localhost', MySQL connects via Unix socket instead of TCP/IP. But I do not understand why connect attempts on 127.0.0.1 sometimes fail. The server is handling a fairly large volume of requests, MySQL reports 1920 queries per second, could I be running into some TCP limitation here?

Comment: look at /etc/networking/interfaces and note what 127.x.y.z the lo interface is bound on. its likely 127.0.1.1. any address in 127.x.y.z can be the loopback. use `netstat -ntlup | grep 3306` and note which IP address the the process is bound to.

Comment: lo is bound to 127.0.0.1 so it's not that. I'm wondering if I should start tweaking values in sysctl.conf. Found this which may be my issue http://www.fromdual.com/huge-amount-of-time-wait-connections

Answer (score -1):

127.0.0.x is known as a Loopback address which is used for network diagnostics purposes, x indicates the host number that you want to test its connection, so using ping 127.0.0.1 means that host 1 is up and running